# speed of populating listview using mysql in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, performance, listview

This is my code for populating the listview:

```
    Dim itms As ListViewItem
    Dim itm As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim itemcoll(2) As String

    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "SELECT COLOR_CODE,DESC from COLORS"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQ, con)
    Try
        con.Open()
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
        lstview.Items.Clear()
        Application.DoEvents()
        lstview.SuspendLayout()
        lstview.BeginUpdate()
        lstview.Visible = False
        While rs.Read
            itemcoll(0) = IIf(Not IsDBNull(rs.Item("COLOR_CODE")), rs.Item("COLOR_CODE"), 0)
            itemcoll(1) = IIf(Not IsDBNull(rs.Item("DESC")), rs.Item("DESC"), 0)

            itms = New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
            'lstview.Items.Add(itms)
            itm.Add(itms)
        End While
        rs.Close()
        lstview.Items.AddRange(itm.ToArray)
        lstview.EndUpdate()
        lstview.Visible = True
        lstview.ResumeLayout()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

This code is fast for populating rows of 10,000+, but If I am populating more than 50, 000, it is slow, it take 2 seconds to populate the listview, is the speed normal or slow?

And also what are the other techniques to speed up populating? I have use some of the ways to increase the speep of populating.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why you are not doing paging?

Comment: Changing your `IIF` to `IF` can save you 50% processing time, if you use a version of .net that supports it.  IIF has to process both the true and the false values every time. IF only processes the value for whichever condition is met.

Comment: You also don't need to do `itm.ToArray`, as `AddRange` will take an IEnumerable, such as a List.

Comment: @michael: actually I have think of using this but still studying how to do the paging.

Comment: I think LINQ can make it faster, I have left over .net since a long time, but I remember learning that LINQ is faster for table scans

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.  Sometimes unnecessarily writing to placeholder variables can slow performance, though theoretically not much should be different in execution time.

```
Dim itm As New List(Of ListViewItem)
Dim strQ As String = "SELECT COLOR_CODE,DESC from COLORS"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQ, con)


lstview.Items.Clear()
Application.DoEvents()
lstview.SuspendLayout()
lstview.BeginUpdate()
lstview.Visible = False

Try
    con.Open()

    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rs.Read            
        itm.Add(New ListViewItem({Convert.ToString(rs.Item("COLOR_CODE")),
                                 Convert.ToString(rs.Item("DESC"))}))
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()

    lstview.Items.AddRange(itm)
    lstview.EndUpdate()
    lstview.Visible = True
    lstview.ResumeLayout()
End Try
```